# How do I make a view always editable (allow deleting and moving rows) without having to use an edit button?

Tags: swiftui

I have a VStack of items, I want the user to be able to add, delete and re-order the items.

If I wrap it in a navigation view and add an edit button this works, but I don't want the other things a navigation view adds, and *crucially* I don't want the user to have to tap edit - it should *always* be editable.

How do I permanently enable edit mode?

Here's the code without the navigation view (so currently the editing doesn't work:

```
struct MyAlwaysEditingView: View {
    @Binding var items: [Item]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            //Title and Add button
            ZStack {
                Text("Editable Stuff")
                HStack { // This is to add an Add button without using a navigation view
                    Button("Add", action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            items.append(Item())
                        }
                    })
                    .padding()
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            //Items
            VStack {
                ForEach(items.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    Item View(item: items[index])
                }
                .onMove(perform: {from, to in
                    withAnimation {
                        items.move(fromOffsets: from, toOffset: to)
                    }
                })
                .onDelete(perform: {indexSet in
                    withAnimation {
                        items.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61285311/12299030?

Comment: It does when using List, which is great, maybe I can adapt to that, thanks!  Currently though if I change my VStack to List it doesn't expand to fit its contents (ie its heigh is just a few pixels and you can't see any of the items).  Any idea if you can do the same thing with a VStack though?

Comment: onMove & onDelete do not work in VStack... although you can use custom like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63833510/12299030

Comment: That answers that then, thanks!  I'll replicate the post from that other question into an answer on this one shortly.